# Bloqueo @RequestMapping al abrir varias pestañas con Spring

Tags: java, spring

Al momento de abrir varias pestañas en el navegador, en especifico 5 todo funciona bien en el @RequestMapping, pero al abrir una sexta pestaña se bloquea y tiene que esperar a que terminen las 5 para comenzar a cargar la sexta pestaña. ¿Como podría evitar el bloqueo y continué?¿y por que sucede esto?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/Inventario")
public class InventarioController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/yyy", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String obtenerGET(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws ParseException{

        for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
            System.out.println("Entro " + i);
        }
// Todod funciona bien hasta que abro la sexta 

        return "XXX/yyy";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu micro servicio con su endPoint de "/yyy" está ubicado en una máquina "supongamos localhost".

Si tu máquina no es muy potente le costará ejecutar simultáneamente varias peticiones, las peticiones que se realizan se ejecutan de manera asíncrona, es decir, no esperan a que termina esa función para permitir la entrada de otra petición rest, por lo que quizás entra la 5º petición, pero la

```
Primera petición va por el bucle i= 2300,
Segunda petición va por el bucle i= 100,
Tercera petición va por el bucle i= 2450,
Cuarta  petición va por el bucle i= 1800,
```

Los ciclos los pone el procesador, por lo que la segunda petición quizás va por 100 y la 3º está apunto de terminar.

Finalmente cuando llega la 5 ó 6 petición dependiendo de lo que estés ejecutando en tu máquina, el procesador estará "que no puede más" y quizás haga un volcado de memoria java o se gestione de algún otro modo.

Lo que se hace es tener un **sistema de balanceo**, es decir, cada máquina les pones un límite de carga, por ejemplo que acepte 3 peticiones, y si entra una 4º petición en vez de ir a esa máquina, la petición será re-diriguida a otra máquina.

Aunque es más extenso que todo esto, el concepto básico es este.
Dependiendo de a donde vayas a subir la aplicación y la arquitectura que tenga, deberás optar por su correspondiente configuración.

Answer (score 0):

Sin conocer los detalles de como se esta desplegando tu aplicacion y las caracteristicas de tu maquina, es vastante raro que se cuelgue con solo 5 requests concurrentes.

Pareciera que solo tuvieras 5 hilos disponibles en el servidor para recibir los request, y cuando llega un 6, el servidor debe esperar a que uno de los 5 primeros hilos se libere..... pero es vastante raro, usualmente Spring se despliega en un Tomcat cuya cantidad por defecto de hilos es 200.

Ahora, si estas usando [spring-webflux](/questions/tagged/spring-webflux) (programacion reactiva), el servidor es diferente, es un Netty. Este servidor funciona diferente, con un pequeño conjunto de hilos (puede llegar a usar muy pocos, 5 puede ser una casualidad a tu problema), en un event loop que procesa todos los request que llegan, y dado que tu bloqueas los pocos hilos existentes, pues la aplicacion queda unresponsive.